# How can I send an email with Timber/Twig With Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm trying to send am email with Timber/Twig in WordPress and it's not working.

Here is my code

```
wp_mail( $email, 'Test Mail', \Timber::render(
            'emails/client-booking.twig'
            , $context ), $headers );
```

All this code does is render the template on the page rather than sending it as an email. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timber::render` will always output the rendered template to the page.

`Timber::compile` compiles the template and returns it for reuse, so you should use this instead.

https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber/#compile